# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../../helpers/oidcHelpers.jsx"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I am trying to import a module but it keeps throwing the error in the browser (Chrome and Mozilla) console

`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../../helpers/oidcHelpers.jsx"` -- `LoginController.jsx?1471:6`

Here is my LoginController.jsx file

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

import ActionAndroid from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/android';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

import userManager from '../../helpers/oidcHelpers.jsx';

export default class LoginController extends Component {
  onFASLoginButtonClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(userManager.signinRedirect);
    userManager.signinRedirect();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <RaisedButton
          label="Login with FAS"
          icon={<ActionAndroid/>}
          onMouseUp={this.onFASLoginButtonClick}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my directory structure to my application. I have snipped the files which are not required

```
app
├── actions
│   └── actions.jsx
├── containers
│   ├── login
│   │   └── LoginController.jsx
├── helpers
│   ├── oidcHelpers.jsx
│   └── oidcHelpers.jsx.sample
├── index.jsx
├── reducers
│   ├── authentication.jsx
│   └── index.jsx
├── routes.jsx
└── stylesheets
    ├── base
    │   └── common.less
    ├── components
    └── drawer.less
```

Tried a lot but could not really figure out the issue. I even try to remove the import statement and change the import to `import userManager from '../../helpers/oidcHelpers'` but I still keep getting the same error. Making alterations does not update the code in the browser.

The code is hosted on Github: https://github.com/waartaa/waartaa/tree/develop/waartaa/client

Answer (score 1):

You don't have **default export** in `helpers/oidcHelpers.jsx`.

Change import in `LoginController.jsx` from `import userManager` to `import { signinRedirect }` and use it properly by invoke `signinRedirect` not `userManager.signinRedirect`

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

import ActionAndroid from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/android';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

import { signinRedirect } from '../../helpers/oidcHelpers.jsx';

export default class LoginController extends Component {
  onFASLoginButtonClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(signinRedirect);
    signinRedirect();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <RaisedButton
          label="Login with FAS"
          icon={<ActionAndroid/>}
          onMouseUp={this.onFASLoginButtonClick}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```